# Как сделать разную силу прыжка в 2д платформере для телефона(UI кнопка)

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Хочу реализовать разную силу прыжка для персонажа в 2д платформере на телефон. Вот мой код -     void Update()
{
horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

```
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && isRight == false)
    {
        Right();
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && isRight == true)
    {
        Left();
    }

}

public void OnJumpButtonDown()
{
    if (IsGrounded())
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
    }

    if (rb.velocity.y > 0f)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
    }
}

public void OnLeftButtonDown()
{
    if(speed <= 0f)
    {
        speed = normalSpeed;
        Left();
    }
}

public void OnRightButtonDown()
{
    if (speed >= 0f)
    {
        speed = -normalSpeed;
        Right();
    }
}

public void OnButtonUp()
{
    speed = 0f;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);

    if (health > numOfHearts)
    {
        health = numOfHearts;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < hearts.Length; i++)
    {
         if (i < Mathf.RoundToInt(health))
         {
             hearts[i].sprite = fullHeart;
         }
         else
         {
             hearts[i].sprite = emptyHearth;
         }
         if (i > numOfHearts)
         {
             hearts[i].enabled = true;
         }
         else
         {
             hearts[i].enabled = false;
         }
    }
}
private bool IsGrounded()
{
    return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);

}
```

Comment: Если рандомизировать `jumpingPower` то она будет разной!

Comment: Нет, мне нужно чтобы при зажатии прыжок был сильнее.

Comment: [Unity 2d проблема с реализацией прыжка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1561756/352119)